# How to remove font feature

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

Is there command to remove font feature that are added by `\setmainfont` or `\setfontfamily`. I know `\addfontfeature` to add font features.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[bidi=basic,layout=contents.footnotes]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main, mapdigits]{arabic}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,StylisticSet=2]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
    السماء، لقمان، {السماء، لقمان}
\end{document}
```

if StylisticSet 2 disabled Meem letter before Alef `ـما` will differ.

Comment: I want to disable StylisticSet feature

Comment: A Minimal Working Example won’t work in the sense of providing the output you want, but it will compile. It should show us the document class and the font you’re using. You can do that easily, but if you want more information, everything you could hope to know about minimal examples is at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is with `RawFeature`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[bidi=basic,layout=contents.footnotes]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main,mapdigits]{arabic}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,StylisticSet=2]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
السماء، لقمان، {\addfontfeature{RawFeature={-ss02}}السماء، لقمان}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: That's a great advice that helped my a lot. In fact what you need to do is to go to Table 4 of the fontspec manual (my version if that of 21/2/2020) and find the correspondence between 4-letter property name and long property name. In my case it was "Letters=SmallCaps" and the property name was "smcp".